# Running batch command in Python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a batch command in a Python script, simply showing the PDFs file name. Basically, the Python script is in a folder `C:\users\me\desktop\python` which should execute a command on a different folder on the desktop (`C:\users\me\desktop\some-folder`), which has subfolders with PDFs in it.

Here is the code:

```
from subprocess import call
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../some-folder"):
    for pdf_file in files:
        if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf_file_path = os.path.join(root, pdf_file)
            os.chdir(root)
            call('for %%f in (*.pdf) do @echo %%f')
```

The result I get is "file not found".

Comment: If you are already getting the pdf names with python why are you trying to iterate them again with a cmd.exe FOR command?  I don't see how this is a batch file problem. You really have no batch-file code in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you're activating built-in DOS commands, you'd have to set `shell=True` to run such commands.

Second, even with that it won't work, since double percent are reserved for scripts. In-line command require one sole `%`.

And third: don't use `os.chdir`, it's bad practice. Better use `cwd` option of `subprocess` calls, allows to locally change the directory when running the command.

That would work:

```
call('for %f in (*.pdf) do @echo %f',shell=True,cwd=root)
```

Of course this is probably an example since your command accomplishes nothing: you don't get the output back in your python script, you don't check return code...

If you want to get the list of `*.pdf` in python in root directory (with full path), I guess that you know

```
list_of_pdfs = glob.glob(os.path.join(root,"*.pdf"))
```

or in relative:

```
list_of_pdfs = [x for x os.listdir(root) if fnmatch.fnmatch(x,"*.pdf")]
```

but since you're in an `os.walk` loop, you'll get the output as many times as there are .pdf files, so it's not very performant / bad design & complexity.

For your whole conversion loop I would call the converter for each file, no need for .bat scripting, you have python!:

```
from subprocess import call
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../some-folder"):
    for pdf_file in files:
        if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):
           call([r"C:\xpdf\bin32\pdftotext","-raw",pdf_file], cwd=root)
```

passing arguments in a list automatically handles spaces in filenames.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, when I just print the PDF file names like in the example, all PDFs appear multiple times even though they're only in the list once?

Comment: I see that you edited your answer: I indeed get the output as many times as there are .pdf files. How should I change my code to prevent this?

Comment: Do you want to just print the files or do something else?

Comment: No that was indeed just an example, I actually want to convert the PDFs to TXT. But if every file is being converted 100 times, it will be very slow. So only the 'call' command is different: `call('for %f in (*.pdf) do "C:\\xpdf\\bin32\\pdftotext" -raw "%f"', shell=True, cwd=root)`

Comment: Since the Python loop loops over all files, is it possible to just execute the 'call' command for that specific file instead of the entire map? I guess that would solve it.

Comment: Of course. Just call your command on the current file without the for command. On my phone right now. I will edit my answer later on

Comment: For some reason, when I modify the 'call' command to `call('"C:\\xpdf\\bin32\\pdftotext" -raw '+pdf_file_path, shell=True, cwd=root)`, it just shows me the usage information.

Comment: Turns out I had to put apostrophes around the pdf_file_path because the file names contain spaces. Thanks for the help!

Comment: see the edit to my answer which shows a pythonic solution